# Javascript library for multiple OAuth 2.0

Tags: javascript, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, hello.js

Are there any popular javascript libraries that provide as a wrapper for multiple oauth2.0 authentication api(s) like Facebook, twitter, Google, & LinkedIn ? I want to allow  users on my app to login with these oauth providers & allow me to get me some information about them from these providers.

---

*I did come across a library called [hello.js](http://adodson.com/hello.js/) but not sure if it is well tested & widely used. Also there are not many related questions here on Stack Overflow what looks not-too-good to me*.

Comment: Good find re hello.js.

Comment: but yet I couldn't find a better one than `helloJS` so I'll just use it!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to have a look at oauth.io - haven't tried it, but it claims to be more or less what you asked for.